# jQuery.mmenu simmilar functionality of the navigation (alternative)

Tags: jquery, mmenu

I am sure some of you find this plugin nice and useful. My problem is that this plugins does some DOM manipulation and hides the navigation and you can show that only on the drawer trigger.

Do you know how can I use this plugin on the page without the script making any DOM changes to my page?

Also, do you know any alternative for this plugin?
http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/

Answer (score 3):

i have made a custom menu with similar functionality as mmenu, but without the ton of code, classes and options.

You can see an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/bjornnyborg/zjLrahpo/3/

I have used it for an Umbraco installation, and it's implemented with the following code:

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
<nav>
    <div class="menu-header">
        <div id="currentMenu" class="text-center">@CurrentPage.Name</div>
        <div id="back" data-target="menu-@CurrentPage.Parent.Id">
            <i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
    @menuLoop(CurrentPage.Site())                           
</nav>
@helper menuLoop(dynamic item){
    var  menuClass = "";
    if(item.Id == CurrentPage.Site().Id){
        menuClass = "root-menu";
    }
    <div class="menu @menuClass @(item.IsEqual(CurrentPage) ? "active" : null)" id="menu-@item.Id" data-parent="menu-@item.Parent.Id" data-name="@item.Name">
        <ul>
            @menuListLoop(item)
        </ul>
    </div>
    foreach(var page in item.Children().Where("Visible")){
        @menuLoop(page)
    }
}
@helper menuListLoop(dynamic item){
    foreach(var page in item.Children()){
        <li>
            <a href="@page.Url">@page.Name</a>
            @if(page.Children().Where("Visible").Any()){
                <span class="next" data-target="menu-@page.Id">
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                </span>
            }
        </li>
    }
}
```

I hope it helps! :)

Comment: This made its way to github: https://github.com/Bjornnyborg/bjorne_menu - just in case you are interested :)

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that you can prevent the plugin from making the DOM changes as that's likely how it's been designed to work (unless you start modifying the plugin files of course, but that defeats the purpose of using it in the first place).

I've been using a similar plugin included in the Jasny Bootstrap components
http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/javascript/#offcanvas

Since my project was already using Bootstrap the HTML structure was pretty much ready to go and implementation was fairly painless.

Example: 
http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/examples/navmenu-push/

The one I went with was a modified version of this which acts as a standard navbar on desktop then swaps to off-canvas on mobile
http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/examples/navbar-offcanvas/

Comment: Thank for the answer. I don't need to ofcanvas functionality, since I don't use that, I need the way links work. Nesting elements from side to side and get the back button.

Comment: Note that the dependency on Bootstrap for this plugin is limited. With a bit of fiddling you should be able to get it to run as standalone.